# Constructing Delaunay triangulation from 3D points

Tags: triangulation

Are the Delaunay triangulation (or Delaunay triangulation variations such as constrained Delaunay) rules apply only for 2D? In other words, to triangulate points with a Z value is it require to omit the Z values first, calculate the Delaunay triangulation, and then add the Z value to the relevant points?

Comment: The 3D equivalent should be tetrahedron and spheres instead of triangles and circles.

Comment: Sorry then maybe I am getting the terminology wrong. I referred to the triangulation as 3D but it is not volumetric. It is made of triangles on different planes as each point has a different Z value. Is a circum-sphere still required or circum-circle?

Comment: Are you talking about a triangulation of a (generally non-planar) surface?

Comment: I am referring to Triangle Network, I think it's planar

Comment: If it's planar then it can easily be mapped to an ordinary 2D triangulation. If the plane is parallel to the xy plane then the map is trivial and just as you described (omit z, triangulate, add z).